# jQuery and CSS transition on toggleClass changing background image

Tags: jquery, css, browser, transition

I have a div with a background image. 
The class I add with this code sets another image as background.

```
$(".imageclass").hover(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass( "imageclass2" );
});
```

I try to have a smooth transition when the class is toggled, but this:

```
-webkit-transition:  0.4s ease;
-moz-transition:  0.4s ease;
-o-transition: 0.4s ease;
transition:  0.4s ease;
```

works only on Chrome, as you can see here

https://jsfiddle.net/ng8d2cqt/1/

Comment: What is your question exactly? Works for me. I am on Opera.

Comment: @Mikey doesn't work on Safari (5.1.7), IE (11), Firefox (36)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be able to transition background images. I'm surprised chrome is actually cross fading between the images.

I would recommend defining two containers for each image and lay them on top of each other. The "active" image will have it's opacity set to 0 and transitioned to 1 on hover.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. I solved this way: `$('.imageclass').click(function() {
       $(".overlay").toggleClass("visible");   }); ` where the class "visible" sets my overlay to opacity 1